# how to tell compiler to do "range based for loop" in string vector?

Tags: c++, range-based-loop

I have created a string vector and want to fill it with a "range-based for loop" but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’
```

Does the compiler not understand that I want to refer to a vector element, not a string?

When I used the classic "for loop" it worked correctly (I could access the desired element of the vector and write the value there), but I don't understand why it doesn't work with a range based for loop. My piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::string> massive;
using std::cin, std::cout, std::endl;

int main() {
    int N = 0, M = 0;
    std::string s_n = "";

    cin >> N;

    massive seats(N);
    
    for (int& i: seats) {
        cin >> s_n;
        seats[i] = s_n;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The elements of your vector are strings.  A range based for loop is used to get each element from the container.

Comment: [The range `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) doesn't iterate over indexes or iterators. It iterates over the actual elements themselves.

Comment: You are mixing up a range based loop with a normal for loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace the loop with

```
for (std::string& s : seats) {
    cin >> s;
}
```

In short, here `s` is a reference that runs over `seats` elements.

Comment: `for (auto& s : seats) {` would also work.

Comment: I figured out the error, thanks a lot.